# SVGCompress (python)

Tags: python

Добрый день!

Подскажите, пожалуста как правильно пользоваться проектом [SVGCompress](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SVGCompress/0.60#downloads)?

Видел на сайте пример, но не смог понять как использовать.
Если можно, приведите пример пожалуйста, чтобы можно было запускать через CMD:

```
Python script.py "входящий файл" "исходящий файл"
```

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно установить SVGCompress на Python2.7.9 32-bit windows 7?